# How can I disable macOS pre-selecting an account on the login screen?

Tags: macos, login, login-screen

I would like to type in my username and password whenever I boot my Macbook. However, when I boot, it automatically selects my username and asks me to type in my password. Can I change this behaviour somehow?

Under `System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options` I selected the following:

[image: Display login window as: Name and Password]

However, when I try to login, my account is pre-selected and I can only enter my password.

Comment: Do you have FileVault (disk encryption) turned on? If so, the first "login" when you start the Mac isn't a normal login screen, it's a preboot authentication screen (presented by the firmware, 'cause macOS is encrypted and not unlocked yet).

Comment: Yes, I do have FileVault enabled. I don't really know what the rest of your comment means though, I'm sorry.

Comment: It means that the authentication screen you're seeing isn't actually the login screen, and doesn't follow the same rules (and preference settings) as the login screen. I don't know of a way to get the preboot authentications screen to show name and password fields like the login screen can.

Comment: That's a shame, but thank you kindly for your explanation.